# Expected performance increase building tensorflow-gpu from source

Tags: performance, tensorflow, build

I have a Dockerfile I made for a tensorflow object detection API pipeline, which is currently using intelpython3 and conda's tensorflow-gpu. I'm using it to run models like single-shot and faster r-cnn.

I'm curious if the hassle required to change the simple `conda install tensorflow-gpu` to add everything needed to build tensorflow from source into the Dockerfile would result in a worthwhile training speed increase. The server I'm currently using has: Intel Xeon E5-2687W v4 3.00 GHz, (4) Nvidia GTX 1080, 128GB RAM, SSD.

I don't need any benchmarks (unless they exist), but I really have no idea whatsoever what to expect performance-wise between the two, so any estimates would be greatly appreciated. Also if someone wouldn't mind explaining which parts of training would actually see optimizations versus using the conda tensorflow-gpu, that would be really awesome.